# Validation rule error CPQ

Tags: validation-rule, quote, cpq

I am trying to lock quotes in CPQ.

I insert TEXT(Quote.Status) = "Certain Value".

I get the response of Error: Syntax error. Extra '.'

Any recommendations to lock a quote in CPQ ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use ISPICKVAL with IF for the quote status
IF(ISPICKVAL(SBQQ__Status__c, "Certain Value"),value if true ,value if false)

As far as your value goes, are you putting the period at the end after the last " ? If so that needs to go away and yours may work based on this article.
https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/apex/answers?id=9063A000000DZbmQAG